Making a List of Values from NDSolveValue
I am trying to create a list of pairs from the numerical solutions of a system of differential equations from NDSolveValue.
Here is snippet of the code:
List[Table[{xnum, ynum} = 
 NDSolveValue[{x''[t] == -(b/m) Sqrt[x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2] x'[t], 
   y''[t] == -(b/m) Sqrt[x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2] y'[t] - 9.8, x[0] == 0, 
   x'[0] == vi Cos[a Pi/180], y[0] == 0, 
   y'[0] == vi Sin[a Pi/180]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 32}, 
  Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"],{a,2,15,1}]]

So that for each value of a I was hoping to get a pair of solutions of the form {xnum[a],ynum[a]} that would fill a list of the form
{{xnum[a],ynum[a]},...}

However, when I do that, I get a bunch of errors of the form:
Set::write: Tag InterpolatingFunction in InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,32.}},{5,7,2,{30},{4},0,0,0,0,Automatic,<<3>>},{{0.,0.0812341,<<7>>,3.51702,<<20>>}},{Developer`PackedArrayForm,{0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,<<21>>},{0.,34.952,-16.8734,2.78506,33.6337,-15.6098,12.9644,29.2254,-11.812,18.7781,<<80>>}},{Automatic}][2] is Protected.
Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?
Thank you.

Well, your code sample is incomplete, which makes your question confusing, anyway, I think I manage to guess out what you mean, the answer is: Clear[xnum, ynum] first.

You have many things missing. I added values for these. (b,m,vi)
Better use ParametricNDSolve and better to write your code on separate lines so you can  see things.
b=1;
m=2;
vi=3;
ode1=x''[t]==-(b/m) Sqrt[x'[t]^2+y'[t]^2] x'[t]
ode2=y''[t]==-(b/m) Sqrt[x'[t]^2+y'[t]^2] y'[t]-9.8

ic1={y[0]==0,y'[0]==vi Sin[a Pi/180]}
ic2={x[0]==0,x'[0]==vi Cos[a Pi/180]}

sol = ParametricNDSolve[{ode1, ode2, ic1, ic2}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}, {a}, 
     Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"]


And now you can make your table
Table[{x[a], y[a]} /. sol, {a, 2, 15, 1}]



Thanks! I had the constans defined in my code. I just forgot to post them here.
